# Is it possible to see what a Python process is doing?

Tags: python, linux, performance, ubuntu, analytics

I created a python script that grabs some info from various websites, is it possible to analyze how long does it take to download the data and how long does it take to write it on a file?

I am interested in knowing how much it could improve running it on a better PC (it is currently running on a crappy old laptop.

Comment: Unless your PC is decades old, the bottleneck is almost certainly the network, not the PC.

Comment: The obvious starting point would be to Google for something like "Python profiler".

Comment: well, it is like 6/7 years old... however I looked for python profiler but the script is running non stop and i'd like to have some info about the process while it is doing its job without having to stop it

Comment: The bottleneck is the network. Profiling the Python code won't help. Your code is not CPU bound. Until you understand what that means you'll continue down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know how long a process takes to run the `time` command is pretty handy.  Just run `time <command>` and it will report how much time it took to run with it counted in a few categories, like wall clock time, system/kernel time and user space time.  This won't tell you anything about which parts of the system are taking up the amount of time.  You can always look at a profiler if you want/need that type of information.

That said, as Barmar said, if you aren't doing much processing of the sites you are grabbing, the laptop is probably not going to be a limiting factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can always store the system time in a variable before a block of code that you want to test, do it again after then compare them.